# Using rules of inference with quantifiers to imply conclusion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

I have received a question for my homework and want to see if I'm heading on the right track or not, especially with the use of quantifiers.

### Question

---

Let A be the set of Discrete Mathematics students, B the set of students of Boolean Algebra and S the set of all students. Use rules of inference with quantifiers to formalize the three statements:

P: If someone is a student of Discrete Mathematics, then, they must study Boolean Algebra.

Q: If there exists at least one student of Discrete Mathematics, then, all students of Boolean Algebra study Discrete Mathematics.

R: If all students of Boolean Algebra study Discrete Mathematics then nobody studies Discrete Mathematics.

### My not-so-good answers:

---

P: ∃x A(x) → B(x)

Q: ∃x A(x) → (∀x B(x) → A(x))

R: (∀x B(x) → A(x)) → ∀x¬A(x)

Comment: P needs universal quantifier.

Comment: In Q the and must be $\to$

Comment: What about R? Where did i go wrong? @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Can you tell me why i must use the arrow instead of the and?

Comment: "all students of Boolean Algebra study Discrete Mathematics" is a [Categorical proposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_proposition); it reads : "for every $x$, if $x$ is a BA student, then $x$ is a DM student".

Comment: The same for R: "all students of Boolean Algebra study Discrete Mathematics".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Can you post the answer? or should i do it over?

Comment: Already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3434950/proving-that-a-hypotheses-implies-a-proposition).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA They answered the question below mine

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So does E become : ∃x A(x) → (∀x B(x)  → (A(x)) ?

Answer (score 1):

A(x) is the statement 'x is a Discrete Student', B(x) is the statement 'x is a Boolean Algebra Student'.

P: ∀x A(x) → B(x)

Q: ∃x A(x) → (∀x B(x) → A(x))

R: (∀x B(x) → A(x)) → ∀x¬A(x)

Comment: If you want to merge accounts please see Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts and follow the guidance there.